# how to redirect url using Regular expressions with wordpress redirection plugin?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

i am using wordpress and using Redirections plugin for url redirect.

I want 
https://www.mysite.org/my-dashboard/?page=pagename&q=pagea/pageb/pagec&id=1&mid=123456&reset=1
redirect to 
https://www.mysite.org/my-first-blog-page/.

How to use regular expression for this type of redirection in my case.

what is Source URL & Target URL in Redirections plugin?

Any Help is appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you tag `.htaccess` in WP plugin question?

Answer (score 0):

I remember Redirection Plugin having a good regex redirection engine:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/